# Adding “with Prescott” to bibliography item’s author list?

Tags: biblatex-chicago

How should I write the BibLaTeX entry for [Stokey and Lucas (1989)](https://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674750968)? I'm using `biblatex-chicago` with `backend=biber` and would prefer for the citation call-outs to appear as "Stokey and Lucas (1989)" (as the book is commonly cited) in the text, but I would like for the reference to read

> Stokey, Nancy L., and Robert E. Lucas with Edward C. Prescott. 1989.
> Recursive Methods in Economic Dynamics. Cambridge, Mass.: Harvard
> University Press.

**Update:**
A minimal reproducible example of what I have at the moment is below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,
            backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{stokeylucas1989.bib}
  @book{stokeylucas1989,
    author={Stokey, Nancy L. and Lucas, Robert E.},
    title={Recursive Methods in Economic Dynamics},
    publisher={Harvard University Press},
    location={Cambridge, Mass.},
    date={1989},
  }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{stokeylucas1989.bib}
\begin{document}
  \textcite{stokeylucas1989}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of minimal reproducible example]

So, the citation call-out looks exactly as I want it, but I don't know where to start to add "with Edward C. Prescott" inside the formatted bibliographic entry.

Comment: Gor the first names problem, did you try the `[giveniniys=false]` option at loading time?

Comment: @Bernard Sorry for being daft but I don’t understand. My question is chiefly about adding “with Edward C. Prescott” to the bibliography entry only. Apart from that, everything looks right. Perhaps I ought to include an MWE…?

Comment: Yes, a minimal, yet complete code, would help to test solutions.